# Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component with a simple map on an FlatList

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm begining on react native so sorry if my question is stupid.

I have a Simple FlatList, scrollable defined by `onEndReached` and `onEndReachedThreshold`.

```
 <FlatList data={this.state.dataTest}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
            renderItem={({item}) => <FilmItems film={item}/>}
            onEndReachedThreshold={0.1}
            onEndReached={(e) => {
               if (e.distanceFromEnd < 0) return;
                   this._loadData()
                }}    
  />
```

MyLoadData method
A simple api call with

```
_loadDataTest() {
    this.setState({ isLoading: true })
    if (this.searchedText.length > 0 && this.page <= this.totalPages) {
      getDataCallAPiTest(this.searchedText, this.page+1).then( data => {
        console.log('data', data )
          this.page = data.page
          this.totalPages = data.total_pages
          this.setState({
            dataTest: this.state.dataTest.concat(data.results),
            isLoading: false
          })
      })
    }
  }
```

If i Scroll 5 times so 5 api call, I have an error

```
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
```

I have this error if my list contains more 80 Objects
A piece of the map

```
adult: false
backdrop_path: "/4GlSMUpzSd3cliYGFJVziSDX53S.jpg"
genre_ids: (2) [12, 14]
id: 671
original_language: "en"
original_title: "Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone"
overview: "Orphelin, Harry Potter a été recueilli en bas âge par sa tante Pétunia et son oncle Vernon, deux abominables créatures qui, depuis dix ans, prennent un malin plaisir à l’humilier, le houspiller et le malmemer. Contraint de se nourrir de restes et de dormir dans un placard infesté d’araignées, le malheureux est en butte à l’hostilité de son cousin Dudley, obèse imbécile qui ne manque pas une occasion de le rouer de coups. L’année de ses 11 ans, Harry ne s’attend pas à recevoir de cadeaux, pourtant cette année là, une lettre mystérieuse va lui parvenir qui va changer son existence..."
popularity: 135.056
poster_path: "/fbxQ44VRdM2PVzHSNajUseUteem.jpg"
release_date: "2001-11-16"
title: "Harry Potter à l'école des sorciers"
video: false
vote_average: 7.9
vote_count: 18622
```

I don't know why, so you can help me.
thanks

Comment: Could you try creating a *running* [Expo snack](https://expo.io/) that reproduces this issue?

Comment: @DrewReese I reproduce on a expo stack yes

Comment: If you've still the Expo snack that reproduces issue can you update your question to include a link to it?